# ListView layout inflater two lines

Tags: android, listview, layout

I'm using a simple ListView with adapter, etc. I don't have any problem there.
There are 3 different types of listview items to add, it works fine.

What I want to have is, to have a layout with 2 lines.

[image]

My code:

I want to have the seekbar in 2nd line.

item3.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/geld"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/filter_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/icon"/>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seek"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what u tried anything...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Linear layout (vertical) to force it to use two lines, first with a LL Horizontal and at last your seekbar. see code below:

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/geld"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/filter_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/icon"/>

 </LinearLayout>
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seek"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"/>

</LinearLayout>
```